# Proxying NHibernate Objects with Castle DynamicProxy swallows NH-Functionality

Tags: nhibernate, proxy, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm doing things considered horrible by some lately, but I personally enjoy this kind of experiment. Here's a telegraph style description:

- Use NH to fetch data objects
- Each DataObject is wrapped by a CastleDynamicProxy
- When Properties decorated with Custom Attributes are queried, redirect to own code instead of NHibernate to get Returnvalue.

Object creation / data fetch code

```
Objects=GetAll().Select(x=>ProxyFactory.CreateProxy<T>(x)).ToList();

public IList<Person> GetAll()
{
    ISession session = SessionService.GetSession();
    IList<Person> personen = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person))
                          .List<Person>();
    return personen;
}
```

The Proxy generation Code:

```
public T CreateProxy<T>(T inputObject)
{
    T proxy = (T)_proxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(typeof(T), new ObjectRelationInterceptor<T>(inputObject));
    return proxy;
}
```

The Interceptor used is defined like so:

```
    public class MyInterceptor<T> : IInterceptor
    {
        private readonly T _wrappedObject;

        public MyInterceptor(T wrappedObject)
        {
            _wrappedObject = wrappedObject;
        }

        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            if (ShouldIntercept(invocation)) { /* Fetch Data from other source*/ }
            else
            {
                invocation.ReturnValue = invocation.Method.Invoke(_wrappedObject, invocation.Arguments);
            }
        }


        public bool ShouldIntercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            // true if Getter / Setter and Property
            // has a certain custom attribute
        }
    }
```

This works fine in an environment without NHibernate (creating objects in code, where the Object holds its own data).
Unfortunately, the `else` part in the Intercept method seems to leave NHibernate unfunctional, it seems the `_wrappedObject` is reduced to it's base type functionality (instead of being proxied by NHibernate), so all mapped Child collections remain empty.

I tried switching from `lazy` to `eager` loading (and confirmed that all SQL gets executed), but that doesn't change anything at all.

Does anybody have an idea what I could do to get this back to work?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that what I do is partially wrong and partially incomplete. Instead of deleting this question, I chose to answer it myself, so that others can benefit from it as well.

First of all, I have misunderstood the class proxy to be an instance proxy, which is why i stored the `_wrappedObject`. I needed the Object to perform `invocation.Method.Invoke(_wrappedObject, invocation.Arguments)`, which is the next mistake. Instead of doing so, I should have passed the call on to the next interceptor by making use of `invocation.Proceed()`.

Now, where was that Incomplete? NH seems to need to know Metadata about it's instances, so I missed one important line to make NH aware that the proxy is one of its kin:

```
SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(entityName).SetIdentifier(instance, id, entityMode);
```

This only works in an NHibernate Interceptor, so the final product differs a bit from my initial one...Enough gibberish, you can see a very very comprehensible example on this on Ayende's [website](http://ayende.com/blog/4106/nhibernate-inotifypropertychanged). Big props for his great tutorial!